# Console Error when using variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, onclick, append, undefined

I have created a button for selecting multiple images `.multiple-image-button` and output the values in `.imagefieldmulti`

```
<div class="imagefieldwrapper pt-3">
<input type="text" size="36" name="lbu_multiple_gallery_images" class="imagefield imagefieldmulti" placeholder="Images URL" value="" /> 
<a class="multiple-image-button"><div class="row m-0 text-center align-items-center image-button-container"><div class="col h1"><i class="far fa-images"></i><br><h6>Add Images</h6></div></div></a>
<a id="lbu_multiple_gallery_reset" class="btn btn-warning multiple-image-reset" role="button" style="display:none;">Reset</a>
<div class="imageListId row m-0 klara-wrapper-inputs-holder multiple-images-wrapper" data-img-classes="listitemClass" data-img-width="100"></div>
</div>
```

The input `.imagefieldmulti` saves all selected images with comma separated value e.g.

```
http://example.com/img1.jpg,http://example.com/img2.jpg,http://example.com/img3.jpg
```

for each image selected, i wrape it with a `div` with the class name `.imagewrapper`.
Then in each `.imagewrapper` i append another div with class name `.removeit` class image button like following:

```
var settingsOutput = $(button).closest(".imagefieldwrapper");
settingsOutput.find(".listitemClass" ).wrap( "<div class='imagewrapper col-lg' style='padding: 0px; min-width:33.3333%;'></div>" );
settingsOutput.find('.imagewrapper').append( "<div class='removeit'>X</div>" );
```

on clicking the .removeit button it removes the src url from .imagefieldmulti value and keeps others only.

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeit', function() {
   var imgsrc = $(this).closest('.imagewrapper').find('.listitemClass').attr('src');
   var currentimgsrc = $(this).closest('.imagefieldwrapper').find('.imagefieldmulti');
            
   currentimgsrc.val(currentimgsrc.val().replace(imgsrc + ',', ""));
   currentimgsrc.val(currentimgsrc.val().replace(imgsrc, ""));
   currentimgsrc.change();

   $(this).closest('.imagewrapper').remove();
});
```

Now this is working fine but i am getting always an error `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

This only happens if i have more than one `.imagefieldwrapper` div in my form. I am not sure how to get rid of this Error!

Comment: creating demo code might help to understand where problem exist .

Comment: Please click edit then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan If i remove this part `$(this).closest('.imagewrapper').remove();` it doesn't show the Error, but still need to have this part `$(this).closest('.imagewrapper').remove();`

Comment: You should check for `currentimgsrc.length` before attempting to read `.val()` when the element clearly doesn't exist (so .val() gives `undefined` and then you get your error that clearly explains the problem with *cannot read property of undefined*

Comment: @freedomn-m checking the `currentimgsrc.length` has solved the error, could you please send your comment as answer so i can mark as solved. Thanks dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

means the code immediately to the left of `.replace()` is `undefined`, in this case it appears to be this line:

```
currentimgsrc.val(currentimgsrc.val().replace(imgsrc + ',', ""));
```

So `currentimgsrc.val()` returns `undefined`.  This happens with `currentimgsrc` (defined via jquery `.find`) is an empty jquery collection.

You could check if `currentimgsrc.val()` is undefined, but it's just as easy / quick to check if the code to the left of `.val()` is also valid, in this case, it's a jquery object, so you can check if the previous `.find()` actually found an element or not with

```
if (currentimgsrc.length > 0)  {
    currentimgsrc.val(currentimgsrc.val().replace(imgsrc + ',', ""));
}
```

jquery generally does a good job of handling empty collections, but you still need to take care of any return values (such as `.val()`)

Comment: i tried `if ( currentimgsrc.length ) {` OR `if (currentimgsrc.length > 0)  {` both work fine. Thanks